# Doubt on complexity of multiplying two binary numbers.

Tags: solution-verification, binary, binary-operations

In one of my lectures, it was stated that when we multiply two binary numbers (say $n$ and $m$) such that $n$ has $k$ bits and $m$ has $l$ bits we have a maximum of $kl$ bit operations.

**I don't believe this affirmation.** When we perform multiplication of the two binary numbers $n$ and $m$ we are essentialy doing a maximum of $l-1$ additions (note that if we are multiplying $n \times m$ we will have exactly $l$ lines,which correspond to $l-1$ additions) of numbers that never have more than $k+(l-1)$ bits (obviously, the first line will contain a number with $k$ (or $0$) bits and so on... in the last line we might have a number with $k+(l-1)$ bits). Therefore, in the worst case scenario, we are essentially perfoming $l-1$ additions of numbers with $k+(l-1)$ bits. Since the addition of two numbers with $k+(l-1)$ uses at maximum $k+l$ bit operations, it follows that our multiplication takes at maximum $(l-1)\times(k+l)$ bit operations.

This doesn't look like $kl,$ in every scenario possible.

Where am I  going wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that, while the numbers may have $k + (l-1)$ bits, you know that all but $k$ of them are zero so you can skip the operations on those bits.

Comment: The statement doesn't make sense. You can add redundant steps to any algorithm to make it have as many steps as you like.

Comment: We were not attending that lecture. In my opinion, you should ask the lecturer their definition of bit operation and how they got $kl$. Otherwise we are just speculating about what the lecturer meant and it isn't possible to answer your question.

Comment: You are basing this on a naive interpretation of the long multiplication process taught to children. But that algorithm was designed to be easily remembered and followed by people. It was not designed to be the most efficient possible. As MartianInvader points out, you do not have $k+(l-1)$ bits. You only have $k$ bits. The rest are always $0$ and you do not need to do any operations with them. That is only the first improvement that can be made in the algorithm over this naive interpretation.